# Qt break out of loop in worker class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a worker class that's in it's own thread, separate from the GUI thread. Inside the worker class, I have a method that contains a do-while loop. I'm trying to make it so clicking a pushbutton on the GUI breaks out of the loop early. What I have so far:

```
Class Worker : public QObject {
...

public slots:
    void process();

private slots:
    void killLoop(){killLoopFlag =true;}

private:
    bool killLoopFlag;
};//end class declaration


connect(ui->stopButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),worker,SLOT(killLoop()));
//qDebug confirms this connection works.

void process(){
    killLoopFlag = false; //SOLUTION. Was bool killLoopFlag before.
    do {//stuff
        QApplication::processEvents();
        if (killLoopFlag ==true){break;}
    } while (//othercondition);
```

The `killLoopFlag` isn't getting set to true in the process() method. What am I missing?

EDIT: `KillLoopFlag` was getting redclared in the beginning of `process()`. Removed `bool` and all is well

Comment: You're missing describing the problem that you're having!

Comment: @Merlin069 D'oh. Just edited it. My problem is the KillLoopFlag doesn't actually get set to true  in the method.

Comment: I assume the slot isn't being called.  Can you run qDebug() in there to see?

Comment: @kiss-o-matic qDebug() shows that the slot is being called

Comment: I'd suggest more debug then.  Make sure it's being set in there.  Print out the status in process() as well.  Make sure it's actually the same flag, etc.

Comment: Also, is process() a standalone function or a member of Worker?  From the above, they look like two different variables.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code that you haven't shown here. Run the program in debug and but a break on the killLoop function. Check and write down the address of the variable killLoopFlag and put a break  in process() where you check the flag; check that the address of the killLoopFlag variable matches the one you recorded in killLoop().

Comment: @Merlin069 I tried this, you are absolutely right! When did I try this on my computer I forgot use processEvents and I thought that it is a problem, but with processEvents auto connection works as expected. Thank you for pointing, if it was not so clear for me, then it is useful

Comment: @Merlin069 you got it. I was redeclaring killLoopFlag in the process function. (`bool killLoopFlag = false;` instead of `killLoopFlag - false`) Thanks!